# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I don't know why am I gettng the error

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'Preprocessor' at line 1 in
>   /var/www/html/phpquiz/result.php:17

There error occurs when executing the prepared statement i.e. on executing 
`$cho->execute();`

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['score'])){
    $_SESSION['score'] = 0;
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $arr = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
    for($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++){
        $text = $_POST['que_'.$arr[$i-1]];
        echo "$text<br> ";
        $cho = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id from choices where `text` = $text");
        $cho->execute();
        $r = $cho->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo $r;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not using the prepare properly, `= $text"`should be `= ?"` and then `execute([$text])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your prepare statement is wrong. You need to replace the PHP variable with a placeholder and then pass the actual value to the `execute` function.

```
$cho = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM choices WHERE `text` = ?");
$cho->execute([$text]);
$r = $cho->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Thanks @Dharman, it's working now. But you know most of the time such problems works without using placeholder, then why is it not working?

Comment: Most of the time it works 60% of the time. You might be lucky it works, but if you do it properly it will work 100%. Prepared statements with placeholders are the correct way to do it and the side effect is that they protect you from SQL injection too.